# Making an ISO from setup and burning it to a dvd will work as a bootable dvd?

Tags: windows, installation, iso, dvd, bootable

I have a windows 7 64 bit setup, if i make an ISO of these files with magicISO, and then if i make a bootable disc using magicISO(dvd), will the disc work as a bootable disc or do i need to download an ISO separately from internet and use this ISO to make a bootable disc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works.. just follow these steps:

1-Run MagicISO.
2-Click button to load ISO file or CD/DVD image file.
3-Click button to load bootable image file.
4-Click button to save ISO file.
5-Now you have already get bootable ISO file.
6-You can burn this bootable ISO file to make bootable CD.

Regards

Comment: but i dont have the iso file, i have setup files, you know, the folders and the setup.exe files and so on. the question is if i create an iso out of these files, will it work? sorry if i didnt clearly explain my question earlier